# How can I restore a TapeDisk backup on a modern PC?

Tags: windows-98, data-preservation, magnetic-tape, scsi

Back in the 1990s and a bit later I used DAT DDS tape for backups to a SCSI tape drive. The software was "TapeDisk" which allowed the DDS tape to appear as a HD. I'm trying to get some files off of my tapes. I still have the software and the tape drive (Sony/Connor SDT7000) as well as the SCSI PCI card but the software will only work on a Win98 or earlier machine.

I have bought a working Win98 machine, installed the SCSI card, loaded the driver, but Tapedisk requires a custom config.sys file. I've tried many variations (guesses).

Does anyone have experience with the TapeDisk software? I'm hoping to find a sample config.sys file I can use in my system. Does anyone have old TapeDisk documentation?

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to access your tape drive from Windows. Drivers and utilities were available for the tape drive from Sony up to 64-bit Windows XP, eg at (unverified) https://www.helpdrivers.com/backups/Sony/SDT_Serie/SDT-7000/

Windows should still support SCSI cards, but I can't verify that. Ensure your SCSI device is properly terminated!

However, the Tapedisk software was a 1994 DOS utility, which could either be loaded in config.sys or run as a stand alone utility in a DOS prompt. As it needs direct hardware access, this is unlikely to work in any version of Windows post-98. Your best solution may be to [boot into DOS from a USB stick](http://wiki.freedos.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_Create_a_USB_Boot_Disk_Using_FreeDOS)!

This information was in a contemporary review.
[image]